# Team Synchronizing view in eclipse pulling a new class from remote repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git

[image: class being pulled from repo]

I have a new class being pulled from my remote git repository (this class does not exist locally at the moment), as shown in the image above. 
In the team synchronizing view in eclipse when I right click on the class I am given the following options (see image below) and I'm not sure what to do.
I know with svn you have an update option, but this isn't available here, is merge the correct option?

[image: options for class]

Answer (score 0):

Yes 'Merge' should be able to pull the class from remote.